# Android: not downloading all files from an FTP server when using Indy TIdFTP component

Tags: android, firemonkey, indy10, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I have implemented the following code to download files from an FTP server that are inside folders and subfolders.

```cpp
void TFAct::Download()
{
  try
  {
    Ftp->ChangeDir("/");
    //Actualizo//
    NewDats(CTemp);
  }
  catch (...)
  {
  }
}

void TTFAct::::NewDats(AnsiString Path)
{
  std::auto_ptr<TStringList> Elementos (new TStringList);
  Ftp->List(Elementos.get());
  int NumElemnt = Ftp->DirectoryListing->Count;
  int Pos;
  bool *IsDir = new  bool[NumElemnt];
    
  for (int i=0;i<NumElemnt;i++)
  {
    TIdFTPListItem*  ListItem = Ftp->DirectoryListing->Items[i];
    Elementos->Strings[i] = ListItem->FileName;
    FechAlla[i] = ListItem->ModifiedDate;
    IsDir[i]=ListItem->ItemType == ditDirectory;
  }
    
  for (int i=0;i<NumElemnt;i++)
  {
    //Si es una SubCarpeta
    if(IsDir[i])
    {
      Ruta = Path + Elementos->Strings[i];
      AnsiString Copia = Path + Elementos->Strings[i];
      Folder = Ruta.SubString(Ruta.LastDelimiter("\")+1,Ruta.Length());
    
      //Compruebo si el Directorio existe
      if(DirectoryExists(Ruta))
      {
        Ftp->ChangeDir(Elementos->Strings[i]);
        NewDats(Ruta + "/");
      }
      else
      {
        CreateDir(Ruta);
        Ftp->ChangeDir(Elementos->Strings[i]);
        NewDats(Ruta + "/");
      }
    }
    else
    {
      try
      {
        Ftp->Get(Elementos->Strings[i],Copia,true); //bajo archivo
      }
      catch(...)
      {
      }
    } //IsDir
    
  }//for
    
  Ftp->ChangeDirUp();
}
```

On Windows, it works perfectly.

An Android, it goes through folders and subfolders perfectly, but when it has to download files, sometimes it downloads all of the files, other times it downloads only some of the file, and other times it downloads none at all.

What could be the problem?

Comment: `NewDats(CTemp);` What is CTemp?

Comment: It is the root path where the downloaded files are stored.

Comment: I have no idea what that would be. Please add to your code the value.

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of issues with this code:

- you should not be using `AnsiString` at all on Android (or Windows, for that matter). Use `UnicodeString` (or better, `System::String`) instead. Both Operating Systems are Unicode-based, and you are using a Unicode-based version of C++Builder, and a Unicode-based version of Indy, so don't use ANSI strings at all.
- There is no point in passing a `TStringList` into `TIdFTP::List()` if you are going to ignore its output.  So, you should pass in `nullptr` and just use `TIdFTP::DirectoryListing` by itself.
- You are leaking your  `IsDir` array.  Use `std::vector` instead of `new[]`.
- When calling `Ruta.LastDelimiter("\")`, you need to escape the `\` character using either `"\\"` or `R"(\)"`. Or, you could simply use `ExtractFileName()` instead of using `Ruta.SubString()` at all.  However, you are also mixing `\` and `/` characters in your paths.  Don't do that.  Use `/` for FTP paths, and use `System::Sysutils::PathDelim` or `System::Ioutils::TPath::DirectorySeparatorChar` for local filesystem paths.  Don't use a single `string` to represent both kinds of paths, keep them separate.
- but most importantly, you are ignoring ALL possible errors.  If Indy encounters an error, it will throw an exception, which you are catching and discarding.  There are a number of reasons why an FTP server might reject access to a file/folder.  Maybe you requested in invalid path.  Maybe you don't have access to the path.  Not only are you discarding all errors, but you are not even logging them anywhere, so you can't possibly know when an error has actually occurred, or what kind of error it was.  Was it an ignorable error?  Was it a fatal error?  You don't know, so you aren't acting on it.

Comment: Thanks for answering...

The surprising thing about the problem is that it does not give ANY KIND OF ERROR, the script runs perfectly, the `Ftp->Get` line is executed with the correct parameters but the file is not downloaded (or almost never), once the download script is finished the application follows its process correctly.

On Androis platform I implement  `UnicodeString` and the download root path is
`System::Iutils::TPath::GetSharedDocumentsPath()+"/")`.
I will try your suggestionsand I will comment.

Comment: "*it does not give ANY KIND OF ERROR*" - how do you know that, exactly? You are not logging any errors. Are you running the code inside a debugger instead? "*the script runs perfectly, the `Ftp->Get` line is executed with the correct parameters but the file is not downloaded*" - what does "not downloaded" mean to you, exactly? Is it not creating a local file at all? Is it creating a local file that is blank? Please be more specific. Have you tried logging the raw FTP commands/responses to make sure your app is actually asking the FTP server to do what you are expecting?

Comment: Also, are you doing these transfers on a WiFi/LAN or over the Internet? Are you using *Active* mode (the default) or *Passive* mode for the data transfers? In *Active* mode, the FTP server connects to your client when opening data connections. In *Passive* mode, your client connects to the FTP server. It matters to the permissions that you need to grant your app on Android vs Windows, firewalls/routers, etc.